# Var in dialog defined outside of it returns undefined jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm opening a dialog using a `.load` function and then I want to grab the values from the fields in the dialog defining the variables outside the dialog function, but it returns undefined, so my question is, how do I define the variables outside the dialog function to use it inside it,

An example what I want to do.

First I request the dialog:

```
$( '#dialog-form' ).load('table_models/add_to_table.php',function(){
     $( '#dialog-form' ).dialog('open');
});
```

Now I define the variables and the dialog popup:

```
$(function() {
    var sku = $( "#sku" ),
    fba_sku = $( "#fba_sku" ),
    asin = $( "#asin" ), 

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
         title: 'New Product',
         autoOpen: false,
         height: 'auto',
         width: 'auto',
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
                "Done": function() {
                             // I want to get the var sku, fba_sku, asin here
                 }
         },
     }
}
```

I hope you understand what I want to do, if not I will try to explain it better,

Thanks

**EDIT**

The `.load` function being requested from a button on page, then the dialog function is on external JS file, there I want to define first the var of the fields from the dialog form and reuse it for all functions on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the function outside the object, like so:

```
var cb = function() { /* stuff with sku, fba_sku, asin */ };
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    ...
    buttons:{"Done":cb}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how about I want to use again the variables?

Comment: Your answer gave me some idea how to fix my problem, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of "'Now' I define [...]" may be flawed–it's unclear where the `ready` function is defined. `.load` is asynchronous and will complete at an arbitrary time in the future.

Get the element values in the `"Done"` function so they're filled with the most recent values.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Newton, But I want the var should be global.

Comment: @believeme Why? You can always retrieve the value. In any case, without knowing more about the actual sequence of events, it's impossible to provide more assistance. IMO it's related to the asynch nature of `.load`, but as I said, we don't have the necessary info.

Comment: I don't want to paste the whole script its a large script, its hard to give a small example for a whole script, look my edit it maybe clearer now.